# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y(x))$ ambiguous?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

Given $f(x,y) = xy^2$, then clearly

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) = y^2$

However, if we set $y^2 = x$, then we get $f(x,y(x)) = x\times x$

By definition

> $\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y(x)) = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h,y(x))-f(x,y(x))}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{(x+h)x-x\times x}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{xh+x\times x-x\times x}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{xh}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} x = \color{orange}{x}$

Is it also true that $f(x,y(x)) = f(x,x) = f(x) = x\times x$? In this case we have:

> $\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y(x)) = f(x,x) = f(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{(x+h)(x+h)-x\times x}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{h^2+2xh+x\times x-x\times x}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{h^2+2xh}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} h+2x = \color{orange}{2x}$

Clearly $x\neq2x$, however, both seem plausible. I believe the second is wrong, because it seems incorrect to assume $f(x,x) = f(x)$, and the $\partial$ operator usually cares about the position of the variable.

(For instance if you have $f(z,w^2) = zw^2-w$, then it seems to me that $\frac{\partial f(z,w^2)}{\partial w}$ is clearly differentiating with respect to the second variable, as $\frac{\partial f(z,w^2)}{\partial w^2}$ could be misinterpreted.)

So is $\dfrac{\partial f(x,y(x))}{\partial x}$ equal to $2x$ or $x$?

Comment: The equation $f(x,x)=f(x)$ is nonsense: either $f$ has two arguments or one argument, it cannot have both.

Comment: I think it would be $f(x,y) = f(x,\sqrt{x})$ but the latter is a single-variable function, is it not? doesn't it make sense to think of it as $f(x)$? Or is the a difference between the number of arguments and the number of variables?

Comment: $\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial x}= y^2$ **only** if we know that y is independent of x.  More generally, $\frac{\partial xy^2}{\partial x}= y^2+ 2xy\frac{dy}{dx}$.  If, in fact, y is independent of x, then $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}= 0$ so we get $y^2$ as before.  If, however, $y^2= x$, so that $y= x^{1/2}$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}= (1/2)x^{-1/2}$ and $\frac{d (xy^2)}{dx}= y^2+ 2xy\frac{dy}{dx}= x+ 2x(x^{1/2})((1/2)x^{-1/2})= x+ x= 2x$.

Comment: $f(x,y(x))$, as written, is another function $g(x)$, which depends only on $x$. Thus strictly speaking if you differentiate that with respect to $x$, the derivative is total (regardless of whether you write $d$ or $\partial$), because there is only one independent variable in the first place. The confusing thing is that we often "mix and match" independent variables and functions. For example, in the transport equation, we write $u(t,x)$, but then we introduce $x(t)$, the path of the characteristics, and write $\frac{du}{dt}$ where we really mean $\frac{dv}{dt}$ where $v(t)=u(t,x(t))$.

Comment: The function $F(x)=f(x,x)$ is a single variable function, and the function $G(x)=f(x,\sqrt{x})$ is a single variable function. But you cannot overload the symbol $f$ to also represent $F$ or $G$.

Answer (score 3):

The expression 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$$
refers to the derivative of the function in the direction of the $x$-axis at a particular value of $y$. This is to say, $y$ does not depend on $x$. If you replace the second argument of this function with a function depending on $x$ (say, $g(x)$), then you must use the multivariable chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, g(x)) = f_x(x, g(x)) + g'(x)f_y(x, g(x))$$
(where $f_x(x, y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ denote the ordinary partial derivative with respect to the first and second variables, respectively)

So in your example, we have $f(x, y) = xy^2$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Then $f_x(x, y) = y^2$, $f_y(x, y) = 2xy$, and $g'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. So
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, g(x)) = y^2 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\times2xy = x + x = 2x$$
(since $y = \sqrt{x}$)

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to realize here is that $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\neq \frac{\partial f(x,y(x))}{\partial x}$$
On the left side, you are holding $y$ constant as $x$ is allowed to vary.  On the right, $y$ varies with $x$.  So these are two different derivatives.